# Calculating total # of times the value changed from green to Red between consecutive cells

Tags: excel

I'm using an excel sheet with values from C2 to K2:
now any value which is above 85% is red and below 85% is green.

Now I want to have a formula in L2 such that it counts the total # of times the value changed from green to Red between consecutive cells from the range of C2:K2.

Here is the sheet for reference:

http://www.megafileupload.com/12w9/Sample.xls

Now as per the sheet L2 value should be 3 *(it changed green to red 3 times in the range from C2: K2)*

Also need the formula for total # of times the value changed from red to green between consecutive cells from the range of C2:K2

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula for red to green

`=SUMPRODUCT((C2:J2<85%)*(D2:K2>=85%))`